Blazor WASM page slow rendering on large dataset
I have a component that has multiple method calls in the OnInitializedAsync method.
One method is giving problems when the data it returns is large.(Estimate of 4mb when testing the return data in postman.).
The retrieval of the data seems fine, but the issue I am experiencing is that after the call is finished, it takes the UI long to respond/update. In some instances I experience that the entire page freezes.
When I remove this method or the data is small, I experience no problems.
The info that gets returned is mainly a string of a html formatted document created from a htmleditor component.
The data from this call gets displayed in the component.
The method in question is as follows -
    protected async Task GetAnswers()
{
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "api/api/GetAnswersByQuestionID/" + QuestionId);
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var JsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Answer>>(JsonResult);
        answers = answers.OrderByDescending(a => a.AnswerId).ToList();
    }
}

I have tried loading this in after the other data is loaded, but the issue still persists.
Is there anything I need to take into consideration or what are the possible solutions for these performance issues?
Any help regarding this would be appreciated. If there is anything else required, I will provide on request.

You solution uses LOTS OF MEMORY.  Best to run on a machine that has lots of memory.

"it takes the UI long to respond/update", yet you have only show the data get in your question, which you say is fine.  What are you doing with the data in the UI?

Secondly, getting an unrestricted data set is not always a good idea, especially if it may be a large data set.  You can't display it all at once so page it.

Virtualization... look at the virtualize component and the components built on top of it. It even supports paging controls for that old fashion look. I prefer not to and use the provider.

The method provided is the method that is causing the issues.
The content of answers can be a single list item or multiple list items.
The content of the answer contains a string from a html editor, and some content can contain loads of images. When there are loads of images, this is when the slow render time occurs.
